# find angular speed given seconds and radians

Tags: trigonometry

Can someone help with this question:

> A ferris wheel has radius $50$ feet. A person takes a seat and the wheel turns $2\pi/3$ radians. If it takes $30$ seconds for the wheel to turn $2\pi/3$ radians what is the angular speed of the wheel?

Would I just divide $-1/2$ by $30$ seconds?

**Edit:** (in response to the comments)  Thanks for your assistance. So would it be correct to leave the final answer as $2\pi/90$?

Comment: How fast does the angle turn: Assuming a constant speed of turn:$\frac{2\pi}{3}$ radians over $30$ seconds. I.e. $\frac{2\pi}{3} \text{radians} \div 30 \text{seconds}$. If we do not assume constant angular speed, then what we have written is the average angular speed.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to type mathematics on this site.  Average angular speed $$\omega = \frac{\Delta \theta}{\Delta t}$$ where $\omega$ is the average angular speed, $\Delta \theta$ is the change in the angle measure, and $\Delta t$ is the time interval during which the angle changed.

Comment: Thank for your assistance. So would it be correct to leave the final answer as 2pie/90?

Comment: The units should be included.

Answer (score 0):

Average [angular velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_velocity), denoted $\omega$, is defined as the angular displacement, $\Delta \theta$, divided by the time interval during which the displacement occurs, $\Delta t$,
$$\omega = \frac{\Delta \theta}{\Delta t}$$
where the change in the angle is considered to be positive if the rotation is counterclockwise.  The average angular speed is the absolute value of this quantity.  In this case, $|\Delta \theta| = 2\pi/3$ and $\Delta t = 30~\text{s}$.  Hence, the average angular speed is 
$$\omega = \frac{\Delta \theta}{\Delta t} = \frac{\frac{2\pi}{3}}{30~\text{s}} = \frac{2\pi}{90}~\frac{1}{\text{s}} = \frac{\pi}{45}~\frac{1}{\text{s}} = \frac{\pi}{45}~\text{Hz}$$
where the unit of frequency $\text{Hz} = \text{s}^{-1}$.  Hz stands for [Hertz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hertz).